# MGTwittweEngine not getting twitter page feed

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I have integrated MGTwittweEngine for getting the feeds of a twitter page to show in a tableview in my app.This thing was working from 2 months but from 1st june it has stopped working.Kindly suggest what is going wrong with my code.

```
in viewdidload I am calling

feed_count = 30;
    [self setTweets:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
    twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [twitterEngine setUsesSecureConnection:NO];
    [twitterEngine setUsername:@"GoodLifeFitness"];
    [twitterEngine getUserTimelineFor:[twitterEngine username] sinceID:0 startingAtPage:1 count:feed_count];

#pragma mark - MGTwitterEngineDelegate -

- (void)requestSucceeded:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier{
    NSLog(@"request successfull for connection :%@",connectionIdentifier);

}
- (void)requestFailed:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier withError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"request successfull for connection :%@",connectionIdentifier);

}
- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier{
    //[Shared hideProgressHud];
    NSLog(@"status received");
    for (NSDictionary *dict in statuses) {
        NSString *text = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];
        NSString *screenName = [[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
        NSString *profileImageIdentifier = [twitterEngine getImageAtURL:[[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];

        Tweet *tweet = [[Tweet alloc] init];
        [tweet setText:text];
        [tweet setScreenName:screenName];
        [tweet setProfileImageIdentifier:profileImageIdentifier];
        [[self tweets] addObject:tweet];
    }
    [[self feedTableView] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}
- (void)imageReceived:(UIImage *)image forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier{
    for (int i = 0; i < [[self tweets] count]; i ++) {
        Tweet *tweet = [[self tweets] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"image received");
        if ([connectionIdentifier isEqualToString:[tweet profileImageIdentifier]]) {
            [tweet setProfileImage:image];
            [[self tweets] replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tweet];
            [[self feedTableView] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }
}
-(void)connectionStarted:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier{
    NSLog(@"connection started");
}
-(void)connectionFinished:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier{
    NSLog(@"connection finished");
}
```

Comment: seen on developer twitter website that they have updated their api v1.1... i was also having problem with it

Comment: Is there any reason for not using iOS Social API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click [here](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine) this is latest and very well managed library. where you can get all tweets, followers, all info

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just want to get feeds from the page and no need to login is this possible right now with the current api.

Comment: with twitter api v1.1 you need to pass oauth token, keys for all operations.. check details here [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)